# Every non-trivial element has order $p$ in $UT(n,p)$ when $p>n$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $UT(n,p)$ the group of $n\times n$ unitriangular matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$. I was wondering if it is true that every non-trivial element in $UT(n,p)$ has order $p$ if $p>n$. I know it holds for the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$, but what about $n\ge5$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. The easiest ways to prove this are using eigenvectors and induction ($(1+x)^p=1+x^p$), or Jordan normal form.